# paypal: how to access the next billing date for an agreement with REST api

Tags: php, rest, paypal

I need to access the next billing date for an agreement using the PayPal REST api via the php sdk.

I see inside

```
PayPal\Api\AgreementDetails;
```

We have

```
getNextBillingDate()
```

How do I access this?

I have:

```
...other code
use PayPal\Api\AgreementDetails;
$agreement_check = \PayPal\Api\Agreement::get($agreementID, $apiContext);
$renew_date = $agreement_check->getNextBillingDate();
```

I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method PayPal\Api\Agreement::getNextBillingDate()
```

What is the correct way to access this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're **not using a method** to return `AgreementDetails` in `$agreement_check`.
The right method is named `getAgreementDetails` and it's part of Agreement Class, so you must do something like this:

```
use PayPal\Api\AgreementDetails;
$agreement_check = \PayPal\Api\Agreement::get($agreementID, $apiContext);
$agreement_details = $agreement_check->getAgreementDetails();
$renew_date = $agreement_details->getNextBillingDate();
```

Just take a good look at official PayPal PHP SDK documentation: [Class PayPal Agreement - PHP PayPal SDK](http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/docs/class-PayPal.Api.Agreement.html)